# How to make clone child element in parent element in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question, I have a node element like below:

```
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

I want to clone all span elements and adding to this new prop like onClick but also keep parent element.
How I can do that with React?

Example:

```
React.Children.map(children, child => {
   React.cloneElement(child, { onClick: handleClick })
})
```

no problem if there is no `div` outside. But in my case I have div is a parent element outside.

Comment: `adding to this new prop like onClick but also keep parent element` what this means? Please elaborate with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const spanElement = <span>1</span>;

<div>
  {spanElement}
  {React.cloneElement(spanElement)}
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

You need something like that.

And here you are the React clone element method explanation: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-cloneelement-function/

Comment: I updated question. Please check

Comment: Probably you can move the span elements inside a nested component. Or use the vanillaJS method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode or use the <></> wrapper instead <div></div>

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this,

```
const spanElem = <span>1</span>;

<div>
 {spanElem}
 {React.cloneElement(this.props.children,{spanElem})}
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
</div>
```

this is how you can pass props in clone element also.

Comment: Please do not add salutations to your post, especially with a link to your website. That'll be seen as spam pretty quickly, leading to deletion of your posts and account. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a run of the mill forum, but strives to be a professional database on programming knowledge.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because the link makes this look like spam. If you are trying to contribute, please edit it out, and review [How to not be a spammer.](/help/promotion)